# Conditional mutate with if else list of character vectors %in% vector of variables. Including test data

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, dplyr

I'm sorting a data frame, where there are many different diagnostics,
i.e. variables v1,v2,v3. The diagnostic tests can give categorical results, such as "Sick", "Sick2", or "nosick". The patients have undergone these diagnostics several consecutive years - "year".

I want to create a new variable, "Eval", which would class the patients as sick (1) if **any single one or more** of the diagnostic variables include a positive response, i.e. "Sick" or "Sick2" otherwise the patient is not sick (0)

```
testframe %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate(Eval=ifelse(any(sickvars %in% sickv)==TRUE,1,0))
```

However, the above call evaluates also years in which there are no positive responses as 1.

I've had no success either with:

```
testframe %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate(if(any(sickvars %in% sickv)==TRUE){Eval <- 1} else {Eval <- 0})
```

Here's a testing frame to use.

```
#Create testframe
v1 <- c("Sick","nosick","nosick","nosick","nosick")
v2 <- c("nosick","nosick","Sick2","nosick","nosick")
v3 <- c("nosick","Sick","Sick","nosick","nosick")

sickv <- c("Sick","Sick2")
sickvars <- c(v1,v2,v3)
year <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
testframe <- data.frame(sickid,v1,v2,v3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pmap` to find out if any value in `sickvars` column has `any` of `sickv` in it.

```
library(dplyr)
testframe %>%
   mutate(Eval = purrr::pmap_int(select(., sickvars), ~any(c(...) %in% sickv)))

#  year     v1     v2     v3 Eval
#1    1   Sick nosick nosick    1
#2    2 nosick nosick   Sick    1
#3    3 nosick  Sick2   Sick    1
#4    4 nosick nosick nosick    0
#5    5 nosick nosick nosick    0
```

---

In base R, we can use `lapply` with `Reduce`

```
testframe$eval <- +(Reduce(`|`, lapply(testframe[sickvars], `%in%`, sickv)))
```

**data**

```
v1 <- c("Sick","nosick","nosick","nosick","nosick")
v2 <- c("nosick","nosick","Sick2","nosick","nosick")
v3 <- c("nosick","Sick","Sick","nosick","nosick")
sickv <- c("Sick","Sick2")
sickvars <- c("v1","v2","v3")
year <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
testframe <- data.frame(year,v1,v2,v3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: thank you, this works perfectly. Why is the stringsasfactors= FALSE required? Doesn't %in% automatically convert factors in character strings?

Must the vectors ```sickv```and ```sickvars``` be in quotation marks? Does this have something to do with quasi quotation? Is there any way, such as when putting this into a function, to remove the requirement of having to parse the function vectors of quoted strings?

Comment: @Silviculturalist No `%in%` doesn't convert factor to character directly. You need `sickv` and `sickvars` in quotes when not in function (like here) . If you want to use them in function then it can be with quotes or without quotes. Answer to which would differ based on that.